# ListviewItemPresenter property template binding issue

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I have existing application running on windows 8.1 and was developed using
Windows 8.1 OS and Visual studio 2013 this apps is using mvvmcross but when i try to run my application on Windows 10 (Build 10586) and Visual studio 2015 update 3
my application was crash and throw an error,

I created another application again with same style but its working when run the application.

If any body encounter this issue , Kindly share your idea please. Thanks

Below is the for the ListviewItemPresenter style.

Note: VerticalContentAlignment , HorizontalContentAlignment and Padding causing the exception error. because when i remove it the application is run properly.

[image: Screenshot for style]

Please see image below for the error.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: Hi Jace, I already upload the error. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Also, could you copy-pasta the source code so that I can paste it into my own editor. I'd like to see if I can repro the error.

Comment: Sorry but i can't give you a source code because its so confidential, Many clients used this application.